# パーティションスタイルがMBRの外付けHDDが2TiBを超えられるのはなぜですか？

Tags: windows, windows-10

4TB以上の外付けHDDの購入を検討していて、このサイトで2TiBの壁というものを知りました。
MBRではパーティション・テーブルのデータの幅が32bit分だというのに起因して2Tbytes以下のパーティション・サイズしか認識しないと理解しました。

https://www.atmarkit.co.jp/ait/articles/1106/09/news113.html

> だが大容量化に伴ってまた新たな問題が持ち上がってきた。いわゆる「2Tbytesの壁」（＊）という制限である。今度は、PC側のディスク・システムの仕様上の制限により、2Tbytesの制限を受けることになってしまった。その原因は、各ディスクの先頭に置かれているMBR（マスター・ブート・レコード）に記録できるパーティション・テーブルのデータの幅が32bit分しか用意されていないことに起因する。このため、最大でも
>
> 2の32乗セクタ×512bytes＝2,199,023,255,552bytes＝2Tbytes
>
> までしかパーティション・サイズを確保できないという問題が起こってしまった。

しかし今使っている外付けHDDの情報をディスクの管理でみると2794.52GBを認識していて、2Tbytesを超えている？と疑問に思いました。画像は外付けHDDの容量をディスクの管理でみました。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

プロパティでディスク1のボリュームをみるとパーティションスタイルはMBRになっていました。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

2Tbytesというサイズ制限を受けているにも関わらず、なぜ3TBの容量がMBRで認識されるのか、ご教授よろしくお願いいたします。

環境

- Windows 10 64bit
- 外付けHDD（かなり前に購入したもので型番など不明です）

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 2の32乗セクタ×512bytes＝2,199,023,255,552bytes＝2Tbytes

の計算式の通りです。セクタサイズが512bytesの場合は2TBが上限となります。逆に言えばセクタサイズが1024bytesであれば4TBがMBRで管理できる上限となります。
ここ30年ほど、セクタサイズはずっと512bytesが使われていましたが、それ以前では256bytes等、セクタサイズもまちまちでした。最近は[Advanced Format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Format)といって4096bytesのディスクが登場しています。

確認のためPowerShellで次のコマンドを実行してみてください。

```
Get-CimInstance Win32_DiskDrive | Format-List DeviceID, Model, BytesPerSector, TotalSectors, Size
```

当該ディスクは`BytesPerSector`が512よりも大きい値になっているのではないでしょうか？

Comment: ありがとうございます。コマンドを実行したところパソコン本体のHDDでセクタサイズが512バイト、外付けHDDで4096バイトになっていました。

ご教示頂いたAdvanced Formatのwikipediaの記事に4096~4224バイトのセクタサイズのフォーマットと書いてありました。安直な考えですが、8192バイトのセクタサイズのフォーマットなどもあるのでしょうか？